# Full Garbage Collection vs. Major Garbage Collection

Tags: java, garbage-collection, heap-memory

so Im going over the oracle garbage collection documentation and im a little confused about a this specific passage

> Classes may get collected (unloaded) if the JVM finds they are no
>   longer needed and space may be needed for other classes. The permanent
>   generation is included in a full garbage collection.

Particularly that last sentence where it says that permGen is included in a "**full garbage collection**" because up until this point there has been no mention of a "full G.C." just minor and major G.C.

So is full g.c. another garbage collector or are they just using the word "full" interchangeably with "major" ? I tried looking at other resources but some say that **full** is another garbage collection separate from major G.C. and other resources dont mention it at all.

I would also like to know if it is the case that full g.c. is its own separate collector did the oracle documentation actually mean to use full gc or did they actually mean major gc ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Major GC is just cleaning the tenured space. On the other hand, Full GC cleans both young and tenured spaces (whole heap in this case).

I think [this article](https://plumbr.io/blog/garbage-collection/minor-gc-vs-major-gc-vs-full-gc) explains the differences among them perfectly.

Comment: Yes I saw that page before asking this question , the problem for me is that in the page the author says " there is no formal definitions present for those terms." and that fine I get what the author is explaining and I understand the difference  ... what im more interested in is ,there is a formal definition for major g.c. but I havnt found one for full g.c. so is full g.c. just a concept thats encapsulated by major g.c. or is it actually its own collector ?

Comment: got it @BrixtonWeiss. I just found this, but nothing official:

A Full GC will be triggered whenever the heap fills up. In such a case the 
young generation is collected first followed by the old generation. If the 
old generation is too full to accept the content of the young generation,
the young generation GC is omitted and the old generation GC is used to 
collect the full heap, either in parallel or serial. Either way the whole 
heap is collected with a stop-the-world event.